# Should the road-trips tag allow for other modes of transportation than by car?

Tags: discussion, status-planned, tagging

The tag description for [road-trips](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/road-trips) states:

> Road trips are long journeys by car.

Should this be rephrased to include motorbikes?  Motorbikes use the same roads as cars, so I'm not sure why road trips would be only by car.

Although we can also make road trips by bicycle, kick scooter, skateboard, roller skates or horse-drawn carriage, those may use different roads than cars or motorbikes, so it would make sense to treat them differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done. [Have a look](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/road-trips/info) and let me know if it's better this way.

Answer (score 3):

I am for including more modes of transport and not just motorbikes.

Many people travel by bicycle or even on foot in the same way as road trippers do.